# Asp.net How to Get Control Width on Page Load (No postback)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, pageload, hidden-field

Please remind that I want to get the desired result on initial page load but not after any postbacks.

I'm trying to get the value of a control in my page via jquery, store it in a server-side hidden field and access it in Page_Load method. Because of that, I tried this:

In head part of page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var tdw = $('#<%= PanelGuageWrapper.ClientID %>').width();
                $('#<%= CanvasWidthHolder.ClientID %>').val(tdw);
                document.getElementById('<%=CanvasWidthHolder.ClientID %>').value = tdw;
            });
```

In body part of page, inside  tag, I have:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="CanvasWidthHolder" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:Panel ID="PanelGuageWrapper" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

and In code behind, I have:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string x = CanvasWidthHolder.Value;  
}
```

but unfortunately, CanvasWidthHolder value is always empty.

What is wrong with my approach? I checked many questions but found nothing helpful.

Comment: Your approach is wrong because `Page_Load` occurs *before* the page is rendered to the client.

Comment: what is the correct approach? @MikeSmithDev

Comment: How would server know that you have set a value on hidden field on client side? Document ready is executed on client and that is after  asp.net page_load on server has finished it's job and sent the page to client.

Comment: @SSA So please guide me on how can I handle this

Comment: One way is to pass it back via AJAX. What are you trying to do with the width that you need to explicitly set it on page load instead of letting it be controlled with CSS?

Comment: Css is not applicable because it is being passed on server side to set the width of an asp.net 3rd-party server component & it doesn't support css-based width-setting.

Comment: You want to get client width (rendered) on server without a postback, for a third party control? Seems a very odd requirement, why not set a width property on panel and use that for third party control?

Comment: @Farshid I don't know the exact requierment but I could say, y don't you get the value of "PanelGuageWrapper" in page load and set it "CanvasWidthHolder" or any other hidden field.

Comment: This was required for percentage-based positioning